# Naudio object serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, naudio

I am trying to serialise an Naudio object but i get this erreu message `[SerializationException: the type 'NAudio.Wave.BufferedWaveProvider' dans l'assembly 'NAudio, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.]`

I'm using Naudio.dll that's why I can't add [Serializable()]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a good reason why you would want to serialize `BufferedWaveProvider`, but NAudio is [open source](http://naudio.codeplex.com) so nothing is stopping you doing it. Simply copy the `BufferedWaveProvider` code into your own project, add the `Serializable` attribute, call it something like `SerializableBufferedWaveProvider` and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, then you cannot serialize it.

Comment: Don't expect serialization to just "magically work". Some complex classes may require custom code before and after serialization, to work properly. Check with the library developers and ask them to add serialization support, if that fits within their library model.